# How to fix previous releases?

Tags: git, branch

Say my product is at version 10.0.

I will develop an Awesome Feature and release as 10.1. My customer who uses version 9.0 heard of that, wants to pay and get the Awesome Feature without other changes, so I will release 9.1.

How would I commit code and merge changes?

I'm flexible in what branching model(master-as-production, master-as-integration, parallel, or whatever) to use.

If I create feature branch based on 10.0, and merge to 10.0, I cannot merge the feature branch back to 9.0 because 9.1 will get changes from 9.0 to 10.0.

```
9.0 --> 10.0 --> 10.1
 \            Awesome Feature
  \                 \
   \------------------> 9.1  (other features are also introduced)
```

If I create feature branch based on 10.0, and cherry-pick the branch and apply to 9.0, it works. But I feel the commits generated by cherry-pick are isolated from the original commits. I don't know if it will cause issues.

```
9.0 --> 10.0 --> 10.1
 \            Awesome Feature
  \
   \---------> 9.1
cherry-pick Awesome Feature
```

If I create feature branch based on 9.0, and merge to 10.0, it will work. But I have to know beforehand that which oldest release requires the feature, and merge all the way up to the latest. Sometimes I don't know which release the branch will apply to. For instance after the implementation of Awesome Feature, my 8.0 customers also want the feature to be hotfixed, how would I do?

```
9.0 --> 10.0 -------> 10.1
 \                /
  \---------> 9.1
       Awesome Feature
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a branch off of `9.0` and then cherry-pick the commits from `Awesome-Feature`.

> I don't know if it will cause issues.

This should be fine.  You may have conflicts you need to resolve, but your 9.1 release branch will be fine.  And if you need to bring in new features at a later date you'll still be able to do that.